# How to check how many elements list contains? C#

Tags: c#

im asking user to wrote four numbers in console, every number separated with hyphen. Then I split them which is automatically creating an list, which I convert into int. But I don't know how many numbers user is typing.

How to check how many elements this list contains in if method?
i need something like this:

```
Console.Write("Enter a four numbers separated by a hyphen: ");
                var numbers = Console.ReadLine();

                var stringList = numbers.Split('-');
                var intList = stringList.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList();

    if (intList have more elements than 4)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Type it again, but remember, only four numbers");
    loop all etc. no matter
    }
```

I don't need suggestions to rebuild my code, I need to know if I can check it or not.

Comment: [The Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=net-5.0), as usual, holds the answer. also: googling the _title of your question_ yields several answers, as well. i suggest you practice your google-fu - using a search engine is a key skill for good developers. (as is reading manuals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Count property:

```
if (intList.Count > 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("only four numbers");
}
```

Comment: I thin better to use != 4 )